# All the available tags in plugin.xml in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugin.xml

For eclipse plugin development, how can I know what all tags are available in plugin.xml?

Is there any list of tags available?

Answer (score 2):

The set of tags available in plugin.xml is not finite nor is it the same across different installations of Eclipse. The extension points are contributed by various plugins who determine the schema of their subset of plugin.xml.

To make sense of this, don't use a text editor for editing plugin.xml files. Always use the form-based editor that comes with PDE. It will guide you in discovering the available extension points and their attributes.

Answer (score -1):

From the [article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Your%20First%20Plug-in/YourFirstPlugin.html) given by [eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org/) You need to set these tags in `plugin.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<plugin
    name="Eclipse Hello World Example"
    id="org.eclipse.examples.helloworld"
    version="0.0.0"
    provider-name="OTI">

    <requires>
    <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.resources"/>
        <import plugin="org.eclipse.ui"/>
    </requires>

    <runtime>
    <library name="helloworld.jar"/>
    </runtime>

    <extension point = "org.eclipse.ui.actionSets">
        <actionSet
            id="org.eclipse.examples.helloworld.HelloWorldActionSet"
            label="Hello World"
        visible="true"
        description="The action set for the Eclipse Hello World example">
        <menu
        id="org.eclipse.examples.helloworld.HelloWorldMenu"
        label="Samples">
        <separator name="samples"/>
        </menu>
        <action id="org.eclipse.examples.helloworld.actions.HelloWorldAction"
        menubarPath="org.eclipse.examples.helloworld.HelloWorldMenu/samples"
        toolbarPath="Normal"            
        label="Hello World"
        tooltip="Press to see a message"
        icon="icons/helloworld.gif"
        class="org.eclipse.examples.helloworld.HelloWorldAction"/>
        </actionSet>
    </extension>
</plugin>
```

Just edit the `plugin.xml` file and put these tags according to your plugin configuration
You can use Eclipse to edit this file using the default text editor. To do so, select **Window  ->   Preferences,**  expand the Workbench entry, and select **File Associations.** Add **resource extension xml,** and add the *Text Editor* to its associations. Now when you attempt to open an editor on a .xml file, you'll do so with the default text editor.PDE makes this a LOT easier for complex plug-ins

Comment: The question isn't asking for an example plugin.xml file.